# WebアプリをChromeで使用するためのアプリを実現したい

Tags: android, google-chrome

以下のようなアプリは実現可能でしょうか？

1. アイコンをタップして起動すると、特定のURLがGoogleのChromeで表示される。
2. Chromeがない場合、ダウンロードを促すメッセージが表示され、OKならばダウンロードページへと移動する。
3. Chromeがバックグラウンドに移行した状態でアイコンをクリックすると、Chromeがバックグラウンドからフォアグラウンドへ移行して表示される。
4. その際、バックグラウンドのChromeが特定のドメインであればそのまま表示されるが、そうではなかった場合はそのドメインへと移動する。

要は、WebアプリをChromeで使用するためのアプリです。

Answer (score 1):

手元にAndroid機が無く未検証ですが、以下のようなコードでChromeの有無で処理は分岐出来ると思います。
4番の特定のドメインが既に開いていたら・・・というのは難しいのではないでしょうか。

```
String urlString="http://www.google.com";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
    // ChromeがインストールされていればChromeで開く
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Chromeが見つからなければダウンロード
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    
        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.chrome")));
}
```